# Prove multiplication of column matrix and skew symmetric matrix is null matrix

Tags: matrices

I was reading this proof from our text book. I didnt get one step.

**Q.** If A is a skew symmetric matrix and X is a column matrix, then show X'AX is a null matrix.

**Proof**

Since A is skew symmetric, A'=-A
Let A be square matrix of order n, X of nx1 and X' of 1xn, then X'AX is a matrix of order 1x1.

Let X'AX = B which will be of order 1x1 and hence symmetric i.e. B' = B.

Now,

(X'AX)' = B'

$\therefore $ X'A'X'' = B'   **...*I didnt get this step, I think it should be X''A'X' = B'***

But A' = -A and X'' = X and B' = B

$\therefore$ X'(-A)X'' = B'

$\therefore$ -(X'AX) = B

-B = B

$\therefore$ 2B = 0

$\therefore$ B = 0

Comment: The step you didn't get uses the fact that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$, not $A^TB^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $X'AX$ is also
$$
\sum_{k,l} x_k A_{k,l} x_l
$$

which is, when reversing the variables of summation,
$$
\sum_{k,l} x_l A_{l,k} x_k = X'A'X
$$

---

your mistake is that $(CD)^T $ is $D^TC^T$, not $C^TD^T$.